# How I can make my HTML5 mobile web app suitable in different devices?

Tags: html, html5-apps

I have created one HTML5 mobile web app and tested in different devices like iphone,ipad,android phones and tablets.How I can optimize the size and resolution for this app in all these different devices?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to optimize your web app for different screen sizes rather than optimizing it for different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive Web Design is what you want. The [Responsive Web Design article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web_Development/Responsive_Web_design) is good introduction and includes links to many other helpful articles.